# Setting Order of Columns with matplotlib bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, bar-chart

I produce a bar graph with the following code:

```
Temp_Counts = Counter(weatherDFConcat['TEMPBIN_CON'])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Temp_Counts, orient = 'index')
df.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

It produces the following bar chart:

[image]

I would like to change the order the columns are listed. I've tried a few different things that aren't seeming to work. The DataFrame I am working with looks like this:

[image]

I am creating a barplot of the last column in the dataframe pictured. Any direction or ideas of alternate methods of creating a barplot that would allow me to change the order of the axis would be greatly appreciated. As it exists its difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) and last [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html):

```
weatherDFConcat['TEMPBIN_CON'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

Or if you want use your solution:

```
Temp_Counts = Counter(weatherDFConcat['TEMPBIN_CON'])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Temp_Counts, orient = 'index').sort_index()
df.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Sample:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

weatherDFConcat = pd.DataFrame({'TEMPBIN_CON':['30 degrees or more', '-15 to -18 degrees', '-3 to 0 degrees', '15 to 18 degrees', '-15 to -18 degrees'
]})
print (weatherDFConcat)
          TEMPBIN_CON
0  30 degrees or more
1  -15 to -18 degrees
2     -3 to 0 degrees
3    15 to 18 degrees
4  -15 to -18 degrees

weatherDFConcat['TEMPBIN_CON'].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: How doeas it works? Or do you need some custom ordering?

Comment: Adding .sort_index() worked fine on my data - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you split the `TEMPBIN_CON` in two: `LOWER_TEMP` and `HIGHER_TEMP`. Then, you sort the DataFrame by these columns using:

```
sorted = df.sort_values(by=['LOWER_TEMP', 'HIGHER_TEMP'])
```

and then you do the plot as you have already done:

```
sorted.plot(kind='bar')
```